# seaborn in Python : barplot appears upside down

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am learning seaborn and I am getting some unexpected behavior.

This reproducible example uses the surveys.csv dataset that can be found in this link: http://www.datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/setup/

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

surveys_df = pd.read_csv("surveys.csv")
avg_weight = surveys_df.groupby("plot_id")["weight"].mean().to_frame()
avg_weight
    weight
plot_id 
1   51.822911
2   52.251688
3   32.654386
4   47.928189
5   40.947802
6   36.738893
7   20.663009
8   47.758001
9   51.432358
10  18.541219
11  43.451757
12  49.496169
13  40.445660
14  46.277199
15  27.042578
16  24.585417
17  47.889593
18  40.005922
19  21.105166
20  48.665303
21  24.627794
22  54.146379
23  19.634146
24  43.679167

sns.barplot(x = avg_weight.index.values, y = "weight", 
            data = avg_weight, palette = sns.palplot(sns.diverging_palette(150, 275, s=80, l=55, n=9)))
plt.xlabel('Animal id')
plt.ylabel('Average Weight')
plt.title('Average Weight by Animal')
```

[image]

The barplot appears upside down.

Why this happens and how can I correct it?

Your advice will be appreciated.

PS: Somehow this problem relates to the value passed to the palette argument, as it was resolved when I chose `palette = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", 7)`. Still, I can not understand why.

Comment: Just as you wouldn't call `sns.distplot(x=sns.barplot(x))` or so, you should not put a `palplot` into the arguments of `barplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By invoking [`sns.palplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.palplot.html), you are making another plot, which causes the figure properties to be set incorrectly. Remove that, and you should be good:

```
sns.barplot(x = avg_weight.index.values, y = "weight", 
            data = avg_weight, palette = sns.diverging_palette(150, 275, s=80, l=55, n=9))
plt.xlabel('Animal id')
plt.ylabel('Average Weight')
plt.title('Average Weight by Animal')
```

[image]